# *LaTeX it!* under macos: Getting "missing package" for simple TeX code

Tags: mac, mactex, latexit

I followed the install instructions on the [github page](https://github.com/protz/LatexIt/wiki/Latexit-and-macos) of *LaTeX it!*

The files `latex` and `dvips` under `/Library/TeX/texbin/latex` and `/Library/TeX/texbin/dvips` seem to be shortcuts, as upon selecting those, the path that got copied into the `path to latex executable` and `path to dvips executable` fields in the *Files and Path* dialog of *LaTeX it!* are `/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-darwin/pdftex` and `/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-darwin/dvips`

I installed MacTex and imagemagick through homebrew. The TeX installation works just fine by itself; I could compile the TeX code I wanted to compile with *LaTeX it!* sucessfully with the `pdflatex` command from terminal, but *LaTeX it!* itself just gives me

```
*** Found expression $test$
LaTeX process returned 1
Proceeding anyway...
Severe error. Missing package?
```

Any idea if I need some other dependencies?

When running Thunderbird from the terminal and then running *LaTeX it!* from inside thunderbird I get the following output in the terminal:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdftex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80520006 (NS_ERROR_FILE_TARGET_DOES_NOT_EXIST) [nsILocalFile.remove]"  nsresult: "0x80520006 (NS_ERROR_FILE_TARGET_DOES_NOT_EXIST)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://tblatex/content/main.js :: run_latex/< :: line 191"  data: no]
run_latex/<@chrome://tblatex/content/main.js:191:11
run_latex@chrome://tblatex/content/main.js:188:7
replace_latex_nodes/<@chrome://tblatex/content/main.js:330:28
replace_latex_nodes@chrome://tblatex/content/main.js:325:45
tblatex.on_latexit@chrome://tblatex/content/main.js:370:7
oncommand@chrome://messenger/content/messengercompose/messengercompose.xul:1:1
```

Comment: Welcome! You aren't going to give us any hint as to the code which returns the error, then?

Comment: The code is in the error message. It is just "$test$".

Comment: Why are the instructions all about Thunderbird? Do you have Thunderbird?

Comment: yes, it is a thunderbird add-on.

Comment: So try following their trouble-shooting advice i.e. run Thunderbird from the command line.

Comment: I did. As I said, I followed the instruction on the page. But the output from the command line does not tell me much. I added it to my post though.

Comment: If you installed MacTeX then you already have LaTeXiT! It is found in /Applications/TeX. If the path used by it is wrong just go to LaTeXiT->Preferences and reset the paths; LaTeXiT should automatically find the binaries in the correct location.

Comment: @HerbSchulz Hm, I am referrign to the Thunderbird plugin *LaTeX it!* however. Didn't knwo there was also a *LaTeXiT*

Comment: So it does not give you the command line it is invoking, as the troubleshooting directions claim?